# Book about a woman general circa 2010

Tags: story-identification, novel, cyborg

I've been searching for a book I read some time ago. It's about a woman who lives in a society where if you are in the military, they wipe your mind after each mission.

The book is about a time when she is no longer in the military, but running mercenary missions.

When she meets people who recognize her, they tell her stories of her past. She is some kind of war hero, but for doing very bad inhumane things.

The book is named after her attempts to hack into her blocked memories, in her sleep, in an attempt to reclaim her identity. But I forget what the title is.

I thought the title had the word `carbon` in it, but searches for that name always return results for `altered carbon` which is a different series. Also `steel` or `steal` may be related or in the title.

I picked up the book at Powell's book store in Portland in 2010, and it was on a shelf of nominees for some award that year. I believe it was the Hugo's but I'm not sure.

All suggestions welcome.

Comment: There are no Hugo nominees with the word "carbon" in the title; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Award_for_Best_Novel#Winners_and_nominees

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: [2010 Hugo nominees](http://www.thehugoawards.org/2010/04/2010-hugo-award-nominees-details/).

Comment: @valorum i know it's the wierdest thing, that's the only word i can think of and it does not reveal anything, editing for one more word it may contain steel or steal

Comment: Titles with "carbon"; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=carbon&type=Fiction+Titles

Comment: Was it a novel (per @Machavity's edit), or was it a novella or shorter story? They're all in different categories in the Hugo awards.

Comment: @Randal'Thor it was a novel, thank you for asking

Comment: @Randal'Thor the 2010 nominees does not contain it but the weird thing is that the shelf it was on had around 20 books on it, so it must have been more than just the Hugo nominees.

Comment: This reminds me of one of Alistair Reynolds' novels, but I can't remember which. When I get a chance I'll do some checking.

Comment: I remembered more about the context and meaning around the title, edits above

Comment: Where do the cyborgs come in, as per the tag?

Comment: This PROBABLY isn't it since a lot of the elements are only sorta-close, so I won't put it as a full answer, but maybe Spin Control by Chris Moriarty, 2nd book in the series (she's in the military first book), FTL causes memory loss except memories backed up which is prone to tampering and she's a war hero who worries she may have committed war crimes.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots all of the military agents are augmented with implants, not so much cyborgs, but i didn't see an `augments` tag

Comment: I may have found it: http://www.powells.com/book/crossover-9781591024439/61-0 downloaded the kindle sample, reviewing now...

Comment: Crossover is not it :( but so far it is a good book